# Outer scope variable in lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, scope, garbage-collection

Why in python

```
[f() for f in [lambda: d for d in [1,2]]]
```

gives

```
[2, 2]
```

Why result differ from another languages (where result is [1,2] as expected)?
There are some reasonable reasons for such non-obvious behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this `[lambda d: for d in [1,2]]` what you have is

"Running `d` from 1 to 2, give me a function returning the value of `d` at the moment when the function is called."

After that list of two functions is constructed, you call `[f() for f in that list]`. At the moment the function is called, `d in [1,2]` has already completed, and `d` has its final value, `2`. So both functions return `2`.

One way to get a different result is to copy `d` to a variable for each lambda function you create. The easiest way to do that is:

```
[f() for f in [lambda x=d: x for d in [1,2]]]
```

Here each `lambda` has its own default value for `x`, which is `d` at the time the function is created.

Comment: Only seconds later ;-) +1

Comment: Yes, thanks. My main question is _why_ not _how_ it works. I only know that reason can be related to mysterious phrase _lexical scope_

Comment: When you create a lambda function referencing a local variable, it doesn't make a copy of that variable for the lambda function to use; it references the named variable. In this case, that named variable definitely has the value `2` at the point when your lambda functions are called. Or put another way, your two lambda functions are identical: they both return the same variable, `d`. So why would they have different behaviours?